# turn off renewing identity

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I am renewing my identity with python script so I would like to turn off Tor's default auto-renewing period. 
Is it good enough to set MaxCircuitDirtiness to 86400 (1 day) ?

I just need to leave identity renewal to python. (and python manages renewal period by itself) 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think 1 day is too much, how about [2 hours](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13766#comment:11) for staying fresh and stable? Have a look at the [How do I request a new identity from Tor?](https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#how-do-i-request-a-new-identity-from-tor) section of [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/index.html), which gives you a way to do it:

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
  controller.authenticate()
  controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

Comment: this way I am using python too. But I just want to turn off tor auto-renewal. I need to manage it with python only, because sometimes I renew my identity after 1 hour, sometimes after 30 minutes. And this exactly is doing my python script, so I don't need tor does it too - I want to prevent situation when my python script renews identity and after few minutes tor does the same too.

Comment: Tor does this every 10 minutes by default. May be you can give it a number below which you are certain that you'll be changing a circuit. But I still think 1 day old circuits shouldn't be allowed to reuse.